# Considerations for using .blend files between operating systems

Tags: blend-files, compatibility

I'm creating a (fully packed) .blend file that contains textures, cycles materials, UV maps, multiple scenes, rigging, and fluid simulations. The OS I am working on to create it is Windows. However, I must send this file to Blender (same version, 2.66) on Linux. I plan to rebake the fluid on that machine. What considerations must I take with the names, content, etc of packed files and .blend data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only major one I think are path names, if you had anything linked into a non packed `.blend`, you would have to double check and make sure that the paths to files were relative (If they are in folders near or with the .blend that is).

You can do this simply by going to *External Data > Make All Paths Relative*

***OR***

*This can be avoided by just packing the file.*

Also, to further understand why this is [important](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

- <sub>A full path or **absolute path** is a path that points to the same location on one file system regardless of the working directory or combined paths. It is usually written in reference to a root directory.</sub>
- <sub>A **relative path** is a path relative to the working directory of the user or application, so the full absolute path will not have to be given.</sub>

**Update:** *thanks to jesterKing and ideasman42 in the comments for pointing these out.*

- Windows uses case-insensitive filenames, mostly this isnt a problem because blender will use the case from the filename you select, but if you rename a file or directory (and *only* change the case) after this is already referenced from blender, you could then run into the problem where windows will resolve the path but loading the project on Linux/OSX (any non windows system) will fail. You might be best off to avoid this by using all lowercase names.
- For linked and non-packed blends, make sure you have as many of your relative paths preferably *under* your main .blend file. Especially for Windows users: don't put resources (textures, sound) on different drives compared to your .blend files.
- Quicktime support isn't [available](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/index.php/en/interviews/item/47-interview-nathan-letwory-on-quicktime-in-blender) on Windows or Linux, so these can't read image/video formats supported by Quicktime.

Comment: I forgot to specify, but the file is already packed. So I should be good?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ you should have specified it earlier, but its added to the answer. Sure.

Comment: For linked and non-packed blends, make sure you have as many of your relative paths preferably under your main .blend file.

Especially for Windows users: don't put resources (textures, sound) on different drives compared to your .blend files.

Any path going up from your .blend will cause troubles ( //../../ -cases)

Comment: 2 more - issues that could be added to this answer, 1) endian issues big/little endian systems. PowerPC isn't so popular now so it comes up less and less but, Point-cache between systems of different endian isn't compatible. 2) Quicktime support isn't available on Windows or Linux, so these can't read image/video formats supported by quicktime.

Comment: Would installing QuickTime on Windows allow loading of quicktime formats? I know this works with many video editors but I don't know if Blender will seek out and use the installed libraries on Windows.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ, no windows quicktime support has been removed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure blender is endian-aware; that's usually much more a developer than a user concern.