# Can you email a blender model from one device and open it on another?

Tags: blend-files

I created a chair model in blender on my MacBook Pro in hopes of using it on unity, which is the VR development software. My unity though is downloaded onto another device and I want to send my model over to that device, via email, or any other way so that I can import it into unity.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you wouldn't be able to do that. There might be [small problems](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202/considerations-for-using-blend-files-between-operating-systems), but nothing major.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm/30907#30907 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143118/is-there-a-way-to-pack-all-simulation-results-in-to-one-file/143130#143130 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44225/why-is-that-when-i-open-up-my-file-in-blender-the-reference-picture-is-gone/44228#44228